# failure linking C code

Tags: c, macos, compilation, linker

I a ma total noob in `C` programming. I took some code that throws this error when I run make :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_rp_osc_adc_sign", referenced from:
      _rp_osc_meas_min_max in worker.o
      _meas_period in worker.o
  "_rp_osc_meas_cnv_cnt", referenced from:
      _rp_osc_meas_convert in worker.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [make_c_app] Error
```

I am using `OS X` `Yosemite` and here's the make file

```
CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
RM=rm

OBJECTS=main.o fpga.o worker.o calib.o fpga_awg.o generate.o fpga_pid.o pid.o

INCLUDE=

#CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) -Wall -Werror -g
CFLAGS+= -Wall -Werror -g -fPIC $(INCLUDE)
LDFLAGS=-shared


OUT_DIR=../
C_OUT_NAME=$(OUT_DIR)controller.so

all: make_c_app
clean: clean_c_app

make_c_app: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $(C_OUT_NAME) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean_c_app:
    $(RM) -f $(C_OUT_NAME) $(OBJECTS)
```

and the method the linker is complaining about

```
int rp_osc_meas_min_max(rp_osc_meas_res_t *ch_meas, int sig_data)
{
    int s_data = rp_osc_adc_sign(sig_data);

    if(ch_meas->min > s_data)
        ch_meas->min = s_data;
    if(ch_meas->max < s_data)
        ch_meas->max = s_data;

    ch_meas->avg += s_data;

    return 0;
}
```

Where the error can come from ?

EDIT : `rp_osc_adc_sign` is defined the following way

```
inline int rp_osc_adc_sign(int in_data)
{
    int s_data = in_data;
    if(s_data & (1<<(c_osc_fpga_adc_bits-1)))
        s_data = -1 * ((s_data ^ ((1<<c_osc_fpga_adc_bits)-1)) + 1);
    return s_data;
}
```

Comment: It's saying the `rp_osc_adc_sign` function is not defined anywhere. Possibly it's defined in another file you forgot to list in the makefile.

Comment: I don't see compilation of the C files in your make files, only linking the object files. maybe hey are not updated? Also, the linker complains about the function `_rp_osc_adc_sign` that is inside `rp_osc_meas_min_max`. Is it implemented?

Comment: @MByD Makefiles have [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html). Including building `.o` from `.c` files.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi  `rp_osc_adc_sign` is defined in `worker.c` - see my update !

Comment: @MByD `rp_osc_adc_sign` is defined in worker.c - I have just edited my post !

Comment: I notice that `rp_osc_adc_sign()` is defined `inline` in its source file. This could certainly prevent it from being visible/linkable from elsewhere.

Comment: I see you used the `-fPIC` parameter (position independent code).  Are you trying to make a .DLL or dynamic library?

Comment: you might want to add a rule to generate the dependency files, then write a specific rule for compiling, to include the appropriate dependency file.

Comment: where are you setting the `cross_compile` macro?

Comment: @user3629249 yes it is producing a `.so` file - as for `cross_compile` I don't know where it is set

Comment: the targets `all` and `clean` do not actually produce a output file (and neither does `clean_c_app` nor `make_c_app`) so there needs to be a phony statement: `.PHONY: all clean make_c_app clean_c_app` near the beginning of the makefile

Comment: in general, when writing a makefile, macros should be defined using `:=` rather than just `=`, unless the specific macro contents can change during the execution of the makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the `inline` tag that is written before the function

```
rp_osc_adc_sign(int in_data)

rp_osc_meas_cnv_cnt
```